# сделать только один активный accordion jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Сделал аккордеон с помощью jQuery UI, непонятно почему, но не могу добиться, чтобы при открытии одного аккордеона остальные сворачивались. На странице несколько блоков с классов .prices-common, но я для теста делал совершенно отдельный div и результат все тот же.

Вот ссылка на код, как сделать так, чтобы при открытии одного элемента в блоке .prices-common остальные скрывались?

```
<div class = "prices-common">
          <h3 class = "prices-common-title">
            <div class = "price-head">
              <span>Название</span>
            </div>
          </h3>
          <div class = "prices-content">
            <ul>
              <li><span class = "services-price__description">любой текст</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <h3 class = "prices-common-title">
            <div class = "price-head">
              <span>Название</span>
            </div>
          </h3>
          <div class = "prices-content">
            <ul>
              <li><span class = "services-price__description">любой текст</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
</div>
<div class = "prices-common">
          <h3 class = "prices-common-title">
            <div class = "price-head">
              <span>Название</span>
            </div>
          </h3>
          <div class = "prices-content">
            <ul>
              <li><span class = "services-price__description">любой текст</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <h3 class = "prices-common-title">
            <div class = "price-head">
              <span>Название</span>
            </div>
          </h3>
          <div class = "prices-content">
            <ul>
              <li><span class = "services-price__description">любой текст</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
</div>



$( ".prices-common" ).accordion({
          collapsible: true,
          heightStyle: "content",
          active: false,
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cvw4sjum/1/

Если это важно, то сайт на Wordpress

Comment: А зачем раздельные блоки .prices-common? В один поместить нельзя? https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/bq6t4fd1/1/

Comment: @Stargazer в данной ситуации нет, блоки формируются динамически циклом из разных категорий записей и разных страниц, так что всего на странице 4 аккордеона

Comment: @Stargazer но дело еще в том, что у меня даже внутри одного блока можно откруыть кучу элементов аккордеона

Comment: Реализация, конечно, немного дикая, но может, как вариант, пойдёт https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/bq6t4fd1/13/

Comment: @Stargazer круто, все работает, спаисбо. Но не до конца понял, что вы сделали. blocks.each(function(index,block){
          $(block).find(".ui-accordion-header-active").trigger("click");
         }). Обязательно ли в функцию эти параметры передавать? и вот эта строка непонятна $(block).find(".ui-accordion-header-active").trigger("click");

Comment: а все понял кроме параметров функции. Вы просто создаете эффекта клика по активному акордеону и он сворачивается. Решение странное, но рабочее))

Comment: Ну да ) Я же говорю, решение немного дикое ))

Comment: @Stargazer а можете пояснить за параметры в функции?

Comment: .each - это штатная функция jQuery, более подробно здесь https://api.jquery.com/each/ , то есть index - это просто счётчик, block - это элемент массива